# What is the equivalent of $watch and $watchCollection in Angular 2 / 4 / 5?

Tags: angular

Hello StackOverflowers,

I am new to Angular 2+. While leaning it, i didn't find the equivalent of $watch and $watchCollection.

The goal is to notify the controller when a data stored (array or object) in a service gets updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 2+ you should subscribe for events instead of continuously checking for changes. Take a look my following example, where I subscribe for changes to a string:

```
import { Injectable, Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  private exampleSubject = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.updateValue('hello');
    }, 5000);
  }

  updateValue(value: string): void {
    this.exampleSubject.next(value);
  }

  getValue(): Observable<string> {
    return this.exampleSubject.asObservable();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  template: '<p>{{value}}</p>'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private valueSubscription: Subscription;
  public value: string;

  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.valueSubscription = this.exampleService.getValue()
      .subscribe((val: string) => {
        this.value = val;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.valueSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Upon the component creation, it will run `ngOnInit` which will start to subscribe for changes (like $watch in AngularJS). After 5 seconds, the service will update the value by emitting the change which will end up in the subscribe part in the component. Don't forget to unsubscribe to the event when you are done, to avoid nasty memory leaks and bugs.

Comment: So i just have to subscribe to observables and then pass new values using next ?!!

Comment: Exactly, each time you call .next(value), each subscription will fire across your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`DoCheck`**

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
```

To detect **[`changes`](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck)** for variable passed by reference such as arrays, which are not detected by **`ngOnChanges()`** as the old value and the new value have the same reference